# What is the significant of using system calls with a numeric value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, wait, system-calls

I was wondering if there is any significance of using system calls with numeric values? 
 For example take `wait(4)` or `exit(3)`.  I would love a link to some documentation of these or an explanation.

Comment: `man` is your friend... `man wait` for example :)

Comment: @vitozev `man 2 wait`, actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the name of a command, function, or system call followed by a 1-digit number in parentheses, it usually refers to the section in which the man page can be found.

I suspect you're actually seeing `wait(2)` and `exit(3)`.

For example, `rm(1)` refers to the man page for the `rm` command, which is in section 1 (user commands), and `wait(2)` refers to the man page for the `wait` system call, which is in section 2 (system calls).

It *doesn't* refer to an argument to be passed.

When reading a man page, you would type:

```
man 2 wait
```

or, on some systems:

```
man -s 2 wait
```

to specify which section you want.  This is usually not necessary, but it can be important if the same name appears in more than one section -- for example `printf(1)` the command and `printf(3)` the function.

Type `man man` to see a list of the sections:

1. Executable programs or shell commands
2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)

etc.

If you want to know about the parameters for a particular function, read the man page for that function. (`wait()`, for example, takes an `int*` argument, not an integer, and returns a `pid_t` result.)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer you will find in manual pages. And for exit() - there is a simple purpose - it indicates exit_code, so the convenience is that exit(0) stands for normal finish of script, all other values mean different errors.

Comment: I think you missed the OP's actual misunderstanding. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you. The question is a bit unclear. Well done!

Comment: Hi keith what is OP ? some people use but I don't have idea about it

Comment: OP means original post :D